# Objects being reset to NULL after being set to a non-NULL value

Tags: objective-c, variables, null

I have two Objective-C classes that communicate data with each other by passing variables through method parameters. For example I might call a method that will pass a variable:

```
ClassX *x = [[ClassX alloc] init];
[x passThisParameter:i];
```

The variable is successfully received by `ClassX` inside of the `passThisParameter` method. I can confirm this with breakpoints and log output:

```
- (void)passThisParameter:(id)object {
    self.classVariable = object;
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", self.classVariable); // In the log I can see that classVariable has the same value as object does.
}
```

However when I try to use `classVariable` outside of the above scope (ex. in another method, but in the same class) it always shows up as `NULL`. **Why is my `classVariable` getting reset to NULL?** Here is how I am retrieveing the variable later:

```
- (void)anotherMethodFromClassX {
    NSLog(@"Class Variable: %@", self.classVariable); // This is always NULL even though the variable is never used anywhere else (except when it's set in the method above)
}
```

I've also tried to setup the variable in a variety of ways in my class definition / header and in the implementation:

- `@property (retain) id classVariable`
- `@property (strong) id classVariable`
- `@property (assign) id classVariable`
- `@property (nonatomic, strong) id classVariable`

Any ideas on why this classVariable gets reset to `NULL`? I can't figure it out and couldn't find much on Google. Please forgive me if some of my programming terms are incorrect.

EDIT: I am using ARC, not MRC.

EDIT: Is it possible that `ClassX` is reallocated and reinitialized after I set `classVariable` that it could be reset to `NULL`? Say it was reloaded in the UI...

EDIT: Here's my `ClassX` and `ClassZ` with relevant code [available online](http://cl.ly/RBGA).

Comment: Without seeing more code, it's hard to answer.  The first question that comes to mind is this: are you sure you're looking at globalVariable in the same object?  Actually, is it really supposed to be global instead of a member of the class?

Comment: Why is `globalVariable` a property? Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: @ash My apologies, I think it's a class variable, not global. I might be using incorrect terminology here. It might help to know that the variables are declared as `@property` in the `ClassX` header file. And yes, I am using ARC. Please see my edits.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted.  Can you post a [short, self-contained, correct, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: What you show are instance variables, not class variables. What happens to `x` after you set the value?

Comment: @Wain Thanks! I don't use `x` after I make the method call, I assume ARC decrements its retain count and releases it at some point. And @AdamRosenfield yes I just tried out the code in a simple command line app and it works - there must be something else resetting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your `@property` variants are instance variables, so the value you're setting is set onto the instance, not the class. So, when you do nothing to retain `x` And it gets destroyed by ARC the value goes with it. The next time you create a new instance of `ClassX` it's clean and fresh so the value is `nil`. The solution is to retain `x` and reuse it instead of allowing it to be destroyed (and do a little research into class and instance variables).

Comment: This works! Creating the variables as class variables instead of instance variables and then using the same `x` instead of recreating each time works!